# Regular expression for hyphen separated floating point numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Need some help in designing regular expression to validate hyphen separated floating point numbers in Javascript. So far I have managed to achieve this RegEx:

```
(^((\\d)+(\.[0-9]+)?)(\-)?((\\d)+(\.[0-9]+)?)$)|^(\\d+)$
```

It matches the following:

```
1) 2
2) 2.10
3) 3.10-3.14
```

The problem with this one is that its also matching "3.103.310" which is wrong number. Much appreciate any help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the first alternative that matches 1 or more digits with an optional fractional part (`(\d)+(\.[0-9]+)?`) and then matches a hyphen and again 1+ digits and again an optional fractional part. Thus, 2 dots are allowed.

You may fix the pattern like this:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBl2lc/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\.` - a  dot
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*` - an non-capturing group matching 0+ occurrences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - 1+ digits and 1 or 0 occurrences of `.` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string